# Send checkbox value to email

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have three checkboxes for requesting catalogs. I would like to get value for all three of them in each email.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catalog" value="Grower"/>  Grower Supply Catalog <br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="catalog" value="Specialty"/>  Specialty Catalog<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="catalog" value="Plant"/>  Plant Source Catalog
```

Here is my PHP:

```
$name      = @$_POST["name"];
$email     = @$_POST["email"];
$street     = @$_POST["street"];
$city     = @$_POST["city"];
$state    = @$_POST["state"];
$zip    = @$_POST["zip"];
$email     = @$_POST["email"];
$phone    = @$_POST["phone"];
$message   = @$_POST["comment"];
$catalog   =@$_POST["catalog"];
foreach($_POST['catalog'] as $value) {
    $check_msg .= "Checked: $value\n";
}

$headers  = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

    $mailBody  = "You have been contacted by $name" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= (!empty($company))?'Company: '. PHP_EOL.$company. PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL:'';
    $mailBody .= (!empty($quoteType))?'project Type: '. PHP_EOL.$quoteType. PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL:''; 
    $mailBody .= "Street :" . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= $street . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= "City :" . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= $city . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= "State :" . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= $state . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= "Zip :" . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= $zip . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= "Phone :" . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= $phone . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= $check_msg .= "Catalog : $catalog\n"; 
    $mailBody .= "Message :" . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= $message . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    $mailBody .= "You can contact $name via email, $email.";
    $mailBody .= (isset($phone) && !empty($phone))?" Or via phone $phone." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL:'';




    if(mail($to, $subject, $mailBody, $headers)){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Success! Your message has been sent.</div>';
    }
}
```

**How can I send the checkbox values to email?**

Answer (score 1):

Use array syntax for those element names to send those values as an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="catalog[]" value="Grower"/>  Grower Supply Catalog <br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="catalog[]" value="Specialty"/>  Specialty Catalog<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="catalog[]" value="Plant"/>  Plant Source Catalog
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I am a very new to php. I added [ ] in element names like how you did. How do I send the values as an array in php?

Comment: Your code already deals with the fact that these values are in an array. That's what your foreach loop is doing. Turning it into a string.

Comment: I am still not getting any values from the checkboxes. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Get rid of the `@` in from of your variables and see what happens

Answer (score -1):

I think You Should type properly foreach() method, type in camelCase Like this forEach()

Comment: it's never in camelCase, you can only use either ```for each``` or ```foreach```